# Wilsonian Renormalization in Curved Spacetimes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, renormalization, qft-in-curved-spacetime, effective-field-theory

One way of seeing the Wilsonian renormalization in flat spacetimes is to consider a quantum field theory in a lattice, where the spacings between the lattice elements depend on the energy scale under consideration.

Is there any analogue of this procedure in curved spacetimes?

Comment: Any manifold  can be triangulated, so as long as you choose a triangulation that respects the structure of the metric tensor, i don't see an inherent roadblock to this.

Comment: The problem is putting a quantum Harmonic oscillator in each point and finding an interaction between them that recovers the KG equation...

Comment: You don't need lattices to do Wilsonian RG, continuous cutoffs will do too. Normally this is done in Fourier space which you will loose with a manifold. However, if you have a Riemannian metric then you also have a Laplacian $\Delta$ and thus also a heat kernel $e^{t\Delta}$ which you can use smear fields, i.e., cut them off at high frequency.

Comment: If you really want discrete lattice cutoffs then you might want to look at this article and refs therein http://geometry.cs.cmu.edu/ddgshortcourse/notes/01_DiscreteLaplaceOperators.pdf